# how to run a function when somthing gets added to Queue in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to know if there is an option to know when a task is added/appended to Queue in python.

I have an application where some process runs in thread. depending on the condition a function is called from that thread. the called function will display a window.

currently its working and the window is getting displayed, my main issue is the application gets hanged when the window is displayed. I think this is due to the call of the function which displays the window was with in the thread.

So from my search some one suggested me to use Queue in python.

But when i go through python [example](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/queue.html#queue-objects) shows that a infinite loop will be running in main thread.

If thats the case then my entire app will be in infinite loop.

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like you need to use `threading.Event`: [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) instread of `Queue`. Or `threading.Condition`: [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) - more advanced version of the event object

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the exact GUI framework you're using.

If you're using wxPython you can use wx.CallAfter to call a function from another thread:

```
def ShowWindow(txt):
    wx.MessageBox(txt)
```

From another thread:

```
wx.CallAfter(ShowWindow,'message from another dimension')
```

This won't cause your main loop to hang.